# C# "Assembly.LoadFile" & disable "DllImport" in loaded assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport, assembly.load

In C#, Is it possible to dynamicaly load a .NET library at runtime with using something like `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile` & disabling the loaded library from using `[DllImport("someCPP.DLL", EntryPoint ="someFunction")]` so that you can't call c++ stuff for security reasons??

---

The reason for this question is i'm thinking about making a generic openSource browser plugin that could run any .NET code & display things like OpenGL or Direct3D or whatever content you want in the browser using .NET. This would need the loaded .NET library to be secure though by disabling "DllImport" & maybe some other things. Is this possible?

Comment: you should be worried about way more than just DllImport.  lots of very malicious things can be done with plain old managed code.

Comment: Is there anything else you can think of off the top of your head I should be taking into account? Like sandboxing or somthing...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an application domain with restricted security permissions.

Here is a general introduction to application domains:

- [Application Domains (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173138%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

And here is the specific permission related to executing unmanaged code:

- [SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securitypermissionflag.aspx)

Comment: The "SecurityAction.Deny" & "sp.Deny();" are throwing errors "The Deny stack modifier has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework"... Funny how they still give sample code for .NET4 using the Deny keyword...

Comment: Here is some useful information specific to security and .NET4: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-code-access-security-in-.net-framework-4.0---part-i/

Comment: Thankx for the great links. I think this info will solve most security issues.